# How to reduce build times with Algolia

Tags: algolia

I set up Algolia a few weeks ago have been liking it a lot.  But today I started to notice that that it would take a while for updates in my Rails application to be shown in the Algolia index.

Some investigation shows that for whatever reason, the build time shot up yesterday from around 20s to 750s.  There doesn't seem to be anything else particularly strange about that time, except for the fact that there were a bunch of 'Get Settings' search operations for some reason.  Any ideas on why this happened or how to fix it?

[build time graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IBvwl.png)

[Index operation graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezcaZ.png)

Answer (score 1):

All FREE, Starter, Growth or Pro accounts run on clusters shared with other users. Only Enterprise accounts have their own cluster(s).

In your case, it sounds like the cluster you've been currently on, has been more solicited that the normal at the time you indexed your data. Resulting in the increase of the average build time. As on many other hosted services, it totally normal and expected. Nothing to worry about.